Grey Screen Error in release mode. working fine in debug



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 60,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Colors.white,
              CupertinoColors.extraLightBackgroundGray
            ], // Adjust the grey color if needed
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          ),
        ),
        child: CupertinoNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          middle: Container(
              height: 42,
              width: 95,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: navbg,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              ),
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    useSafeArea: true,
                    context: context,
                    isScrollControlled: true,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return SearchSheet();
                    },
                  );
                },
                icon: const Icon(
                  CupertinoIcons.plus,
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                color: Colors.black,
                hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              )),
          trailing: Container(
              height: 35,
              width: 35,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: navbg,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context,
                      isScrollControlled: true,
                      useSafeArea: true,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return SettingsBottomSheet(
                          webViewController: _webViewController,
                          currentUrl: _currentUrl,
                          currentTitle: _currentTitle,
                        );
                      });
                },
                icon: const SizedBox(
                  child: Icon(
                    size: 20,
                    CupertinoIcons.chevron_up,
                  ),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                color: Colors.black,
                hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              )),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            return _handleBackPress(); // Handle back press with animation
          },
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: InAppWebView(
                      initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                        url: WebUri(_buildInitialUrl(widget.query)),
                      ),
                      initialOptions: _options,
                      onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                        _webViewController = controller;
                      },
                      onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                        setState(() {
                          _currentUrl = url.toString();
                          isLoading = true; // Page is loading
                        });
                      },
                      onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                        setState(() {
                          _currentUrl = url.toString();
                          isLoading = false;
                        });

                        // If the current URL is a Google search result, hide the search bar
                        if (_currentUrl.contains('google.com/search')) {
                          // Injecting JavaScript to hide Google search elements
                          await _webViewController
                              .evaluateJavascript(source: '''
                          (function() {
                            var googleBar = document.getElementById('searchform');
                            if (googleBar) googleBar.style.display = 'none';
            
                            var googleLogo = document.querySelector('img[alt="Google"]');
                            if (googleLogo) googleLogo.style.display = 'none';
            
                            var topNav = document.querySelector('div#top_nav');
                            if (topNav) topNav.style.display = 'none';
            
                            var footer = document.querySelector('footer');
                            if (footer) footer.style.display = 'none';
            
                            var sidePanel = document.querySelector('div#rhs');
                            if (sidePanel) sidePanel.style.display = 'none';
                          })();
                        ''');
                        }
                      },
                      onTitleChanged: (controller, title) {
                        setState(() {
                          _currentTitle = title ?? '';
                        });
                      },
                      shouldOverrideUrlLoading:
                          (controller, navigationAction) async {
                        var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;

                        if (uri.scheme == "http" || uri.scheme == "https") {
                          return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                        }

                        return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  isLoading // Use the state variable for the loading state
                      ? Positioned(
                          bottom: 0,
                          left: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          child: WaterWave(),
                        )
                      : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Everything is working fine in debug but in release a grey screen comes and doesn't shows the webview.  I've provided all permissions for release.

Try running your app by flutter run --release command, and see if it works fine.

Hi Ansh, You should remore Expanded Widget. The error is due to Expanded widget . You should be very care ful while using Expanded Widget in Column. Or You can remove Colum in Stack widget. try it.

I tried it @RahulKushwaha but it is still not working ....can you please tryna run it in your pc ....should comment those variables not listed in the code and set the query as a constant value ...

have you tried flutter run --release

To resolve the issues of Grey Screen in ReleaseMode. You should always  care about how to use Stack and Column/Row ,Flex and Expanded Widget .Kindly follow this structre in your code to resolve the isssue . Don't use Column/Row widget inside Stack Widget
               Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('sdfsdf')),
    
                  ),
                  true // Use the state variable for the loading state
                      ? Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: SizedBox(),
                  )
                      : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                ],
              ),


i tried it already still ain't working...should I give the code to you ...try it on your desktop please..

I had tried your code . I have removed Colum and Expanded .After this it is working .

@AnshSharma have you try flutter run --release . This command will you giv ethe exact issues on relase mode . try it once . If not resove , then share your code to me on my email id = rahulkushwaha482@gmail.com
